# If $F(t,x)$ decreases in $x$ for every $t$, show that if $f,g$ satisfy the equation $x' = F(t,x)$, then $|f(t)-g(t)|$ monotonically decreases.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given a decreasing function $F(t,x)$ by $x$ for every $t$, show that if $f,g$ satisfy the equation $x' = F(t,x)$, $|f(t)-g(t)|$ monotonically decreases.

I've tried deriving, I've tried plugging in some things to no avail. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h(t)=(f(t)-g(t))^2$. Then
$$
h'(t)=2\,(f(t)-g(t))(f'(t)-g'(t))=2\,(f(t)-g(t))\,(F(t,f(t))-F(t,g(t))\le0.
$$